# Using 2 index's of a list as arguments for lambda in map

Tags: python, lambda

I'm receiving data which I'm putting into a list and want to calculate something using the two index's of my new list using python map & lambda.

I'm currently using this code which gives me an error of

```
TypeError: argument 2 to map() must support iteration

for i in range(int(raw_input())):
    a = map(float, raw_input().split(' '))
    print map(lambda x, y: x / (y^2), a[0], a[1])
```

The data I'm using

```
47 1.30
84 2.45
52 1.61
118 2.05
70 1.67
75 1.58
```

Comment: It looks as if you're trying to do `print a[0] / (a[1]^2)`, with no need to involve `map`. Did you know that `^` is binary XOR, and that exponentiation is `**`? So the next problem you'll hit is that you cant use `^` with floats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map

> map(function, iterable, ...)
>   Apply function to every item of iterable and return a list of the results...

`a` is iterable, because `raw_input().split(' ')` is iterable, but `a[0]` and `a[1]` are not.

You should just `print a[0] / a[1]**2`

Correct input

```
6
47 1.30
84 2.45
52 1.61
118 2.05
70 1.67
75 1.58
```

And code

```
for i in range(int(raw_input())):
    a = map(float, raw_input().split(' '))
    print a[0] / a[1]**2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the array as a parameter to the lambda, and access the elements inside the lambda using its indexes:

```
print map(lambda x: x[0]/(x[1]**2), [a])
```

Also, you're using the bitwise XOR operator (^), not the "power" operator (**)

But... I don't see the point of using a lambda here, you just want to do some calculation of those 2 elements.
So you can just do:

```
print a[0]/a[1]**2
```

Comment: Than you should pass `a` in a list `print map(lambda x: x[0]/(x[1]**2), [a])` and output would be a list with a single element.

Comment: @atn Thanks for the correction, indeed a is not a list. I'll update my answer.

Comment: But in that case, why is he using a lambda in first place?

Answer (score -1):

Rather than using `map`, you can use `reduce` which suits your use case

```
for i in range(int(raw_input())):
    a = map(float, raw_input().split(' '))
    print reduce(lambda x, y: x / (y^2), a)
```